# Easiest way to "cherry-pick a merge"

Tags: git, merge, git-rebase, git-workflow

I know the title is a little woolly - hence the quotes!

Say I have a branch, `b_feature` that was branched from and merged into the main development branch `b_master`. There exists another branch, `b_release`, that I wish to add these changes to (as a point release). `b_master` and `b_release` have been diverged and will never be merged again.

```
---------Bm----k1-----Mm-----> b_master (k1 isn't to be included in b_release)
 \        \          /
  \        c1--c2--c3  (b_feature)
   \
    \----Br---------Mr-----> b_release
          \        / 
           cA-cB-cC
```

I know I can cherry-pick the whole thing as a single diff with `git cherry-pick -m Mm`, giving

```
     ----Br--Squashed----> b_release
```

where `Squashed` is a commit containing all the changes of the feature, with the message of the merge `Mm`.

But what if I want to retain the change history and the individual commit messages? I can always manually cherry-pick with this approximate workflow:

```
git checkout b_release
git checkout -b b_release_feature
git cherry-pick c1^..c3
git checkout b_release
git merge b_release_feature
git commit --amend --reedit-message=Mm
git branch -d b_release_feature
```

But this seems like a clunky workaround to a more elegant solution that I don't know!

`rebase --onto b_release Bm Mm` also doesn't seem to produce the result I am looking for.

Any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think rebase is a more proper tool than cherry-pick here, although the difference is minor. Here is how I would have done it. First attach the b_release_feature branch to the source branch and then rebase it onto the target branch.

```
git checkout -b b_release_feature c3
git rebase --onto b_release c1^ b_release_feature
git checkout b_release
git merge b_release_feature
git commit --amend --reedit-message=Mm
git branch -d b_release_feature
```

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I want to retain the change history and the individual
> commit messages?

Then I see no reason not to create a true merge into `b_release`.

```bash
git checkout b_release
git merge ":/c3"
```

Giving you

```
---------Bm----k1-----Mm-----> b_master (k1 isn't to be included in b_release)
 \        \
  \        c1--c2--c3 \
   \                   \
    \----Br---------Mr--Mc3---> b_release
          \        /
           cA-cB-cC
```

And then (don’t know why you want this message)

```bash
message=$(git log -1 --format=%B ":/Merge branch 'b_feature'")
git commit --amend --message="$message"
```

Having multiple commits with both the same message and the same changes
(diffs) in the history is confusing. Sometimes it is necessary because
you have to do a cherry-pick, but this doesn’t look like such a case to
me.

### Setup

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -mInit
git commit --allow-empty -m'After init'
git commit --allow-empty -mBm
git commit --allow-empty -mk1
git checkout -b
git checkout @~
git checkout -b b_feature
git commit --allow-empty -mc1
git commit --allow-empty -mc2
git commit --allow-empty -mc3
git checkout main
git merge --no-ff b_feature
git checkout ':/After init'
git checkout -b b_release
git commit --allow-empty -mBr
git checkout -b other
git commit --allow-empty -mCa
git commit --allow-empty -mCb
git commit --allow-empty -mCc
git checkout -
git merge --no-ff other
git checkout main
```